# AS3 - Finding an objects x and y position relative to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to ActionScript 3 and I have a character which you can control, the screen scrolls right along the stage and he can fire missiles.
The problem I'm getting is the missiles are created via these co-ords:

```
        bullet.x = hero.mc.x;
        bullet.y = hero.mc.y
```

These work fine untill the screen has scrolled to the right. I assume it's because the bullets are being spawned as a result of them using the canvas x,y and not the stages x,y
So i'm wondering how to find out the x and y of my hero in relative to the canvas so i can spawn the missiles on top of him!

Thanks, and if you need any more information let me know, I'm new to all this. Thank you.

Comment: you'd better created a `Sprite` with `alpha = 0`of the size of your flashplayer window and placed your hero and missiles and everything interactive there, leaving the scrolling background on a layer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`localToGlobal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) and [`globalToLocal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29). Your solution would be something like:

```
bulletPos = bullet.parent.localToGlobal(new Point(bullet.x, bullet.y));
```

Beware, though, as those are last resort functions. Normally, you'd have all your elements using the same 'layer', so comparisons are easier and faster.

Comment: I tried getting the x and y of that and it is giving me the bullets x and y?

Comment: Well, that will give you the global x,y - that ism the "stage" x and y. If that's still the wrong coordinate space for you, can do the opposite: either read the x,y of your other items (the hero?) or convert back to the desired coordinate space (`localToGlobal` first, then `globalToLocal` to your desired coordinate space, e.g. the hero or the hero parent).